# Compara Two-Dimensional(2D) arrays and record output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having 2xTwo-Dimensional arrays with different amounts of data but first value(ID) is the same.

First array:

```
[ [00100024001, 1, 'Caka iela', 29A],  [00100024002, 0, 'Caka iela', 29A], [00100024003, 1, 'Caka iela', 29B] ]
```

Second array

```
[ [00100024001, 'Caka iela'],  [00100024002, 'Caka iela'] ]
```

So the difference between them is the number of values and first array has `00100024003` record.

What i need to do? I need to compate and output the `00100024003` record.

It's done now in this way

```
something = []
compare_it = first_array.map {|key, value| key} - second_array.map {|key, value| key}
compare_it.each do |value|
something = first_array.detect {|key, value| key == value}
end
return something
```

This way is so bad, so maybe anyone has an idea how to make it better?

Regards,
V.B.

Comment: So what's the desired output from your example? is it `[00100024003]`?

Comment: Its should returnan an array `[00100024003, some data, some data, some data]`

Comment: Can you fill in the `some data`s with values so I can see if you want the value of the the element at that position of `first_array`, or the different `some data`s? I can't tell what determines the output with the generic values in place

Comment: No-no-no. There is nothing to deal with `some_data`(they should stay as they are). Check should be made only by first value (ID) that is mentioned. So he should check those 2 arrays, output back only `[00100024003, some data, some data, some data]` because its uniq and exists only in 1 array.

Comment: So the desired output is `[00100024003, 1, 'Caka iela', 29B]`?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
first_array =  [[1, 'foo'], [4, 'bar'], [5, 'baz', 'bang']].map {|a| a[0]}
second_array = [[1, 'foo'], [2, 'bar'], [3, 'baz', 'bang']].map {|a| a[0]}
second_array - first_array | first_array - second_array
=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

That'll get you a unique list of the unique numbers between both arrays

Comment: This make sens, but `['foo', 'bar', 'bang']` should've been passed too.

Comment: I can't make sense of your question with `some data` in there. You should change those to be unique values so we can see what is expected in the output.

Comment: Okay, i've inserted some values there.